# AngularJs not updating view variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I am having a situation here, my website is built with angularjs. My entire routes are managed through angular. After my successful login, I  redirect user to dashboard page. I have a show hide condition on an element, which stopped working now. Here's the code:

```
<div id="TilesController" ng-show="ShowTiles" ng-controller="TilesController">
                <div class="" id="tiles" ng-include src="'tiles.html'"></div>
            </div>
```

So tiles are only visible to loggedin users. After login, tiles should be visible, I listen to routechangesuccess event and change it according, but its not working.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, next, current) {
    if(userLoggedIn !== undefined){
        $scope.ShowTiles = true;
    }
});
```

But this is not enabling the tile, though if I `console.log($scope.ShowTiles);` it shows true. I tried safeapply, but still not helping, but if I refresh the entire page, then it works.

Comment: You're probably not updating the right scope. Where is this event handling code defined?

Comment: off topic: you should be using `ng-if` rather than `ng-show` since this will not render the tiles. Otherwise, they are just hidden and users may enable them easily.

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the ng-show directive inside the controller scope? At this point i am not sure if you are updating  the userLoggedIn variable, you maybe want to attach it to the $scope.

```
  <div id="TilesController" ng-controller="TilesController">
                    <div ng-show="ShowTiles" id="tiles" ng-include src="'tiles.html'"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Did you bind the userLoggedIn to the $scope? Besides the event is tight to the routeChangeSuccess, so to fired it have to change the route will have to change and then you are not in the same controller isn't? Please provide some code.